# Java Realm get latest inserted item

Tags: java, android, realm

In Realm database solution how can i get latest inserted item with best performance?

this code is my solution to resolve that

```
List<Transactions> allItems = realm.where(Transactions.class).findAll().sort("createdAt", Sort.DESCENDING);
String             latestId = allItems.get(0).getId();
getUserLatestTransactions(Integer.parseInt(latestId));
```

is there any other solution or Realm has implement that?

Comment: I learned the hard way that hiding integers in Strings is a terrible idea!! Use longs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what you could do - considering Realm reads make no copies, meaning it is not expensive and won't affect your UI thread much, after storing your item, you can `findAllSorted("createdAt)` or `findAllSorted("id")`, then find last id using `last()` method like this:

```
//after commitTransaction, 

RealmResults<Transactions> allTransactions = realm.where(Transactions.class).findAllSorted("createdAt");

//If you have an incrementing id column, do this
long lastInsertedId = allTransactions.last().getId();
```

This should give you the last inserted ID of the given model.

It is also important to mention that for this to work, you MUST have a column in your model like this with id;

```
public class Transactions extends RealmObject{

   @PrimaryKey @Index
   private long id;

   //getters and setters accordingly!
}
```

I hope this helps! Good luck and happy coding!

**UPDATE**

I just realized that `realm.copyToRealm(obj)` returns an object!

That means you can simply do this:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
Transactions transaction = realm.copyToRealm(newTransaction);
long id = transaction.getId();
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Please try this and let me know!

Comment: Thanks sir, no any other solution to get that without fetch all data to List? like with mysql solution `last_insert_id()` yes?

Comment: I have not seen any other solution at the moment but I will keep searching and will update you if I find one;

Comment: Thank you! I have some good news for you too; you can get the object you just stored because realm returns the object; let me update the answer

Comment: `long id = transaction.getId();` is very good when we want to get latest row after insert data, Thanks to update your post sir :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Transactions item = realm.where(Transactions.class).findAll().last()
```

Note:if you want only get last insert data,no sort method

Comment: It would be useful to format the code so it's clear what's actual code and what's explanatory text.

Answer (score 1):

```
val obj = realm.where<Transactions>()
                .sort("createdAt", Sort.DESCENDING)
                .findFirst()

if(obj != null){
   val latestId = obj.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Id is unique & incremental you can sort by it or put the time as long value and do same as above it should work.